# Pandas - Find Turning Points

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas column, I want to find each turning point in the data and save to a new column.

```
Index Col A
 1     1
 2     3
 3     5
 4     4
 5     8
 6     1
 7     2
 8     7
 9     5
 10    3
```

To find the turning point I can use `index -1 > index < index+1` to produce

```
Index Col A  TP
 1     1     0
 2     3     0 
 3     5     1 #turning point
 4     4     1 
 5     8     1
 6     1     1
 7     2     0
 8     7     0
 9     5     0
 10    3     0
```

However I think it's more accurate to use a 5 point calculation (`index-2 > index -1 > index < index+1 < index+2` or the inverse) to prevent so many false positives.

```
Index Col A  TP
 1     1     0
 2     3     0 
 3     5     0
 4     4     0 
 5     8     0
 6     1     0
 7     2     0
 8     7     1
 9     5     0
 10    3     0
```

How do I do this in pandas with so many conditions? a complex np.where?

Comment: How do you define your turning point? What's the expected result for your sample data frame?

Comment: I included them. If using a 5 point calculation it is `value at index-2 > index -1 > index < index+1 < index+2` or the inverse which is `value at index-2 < index -1 < index > index+1 > index+2` which then prints a 0 or 1 in the new column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got to do a bit of shifting:

```
df["TP"] = ((df["Col A"].shift(-2) < df["Col A"].shift(-1)) & 
            (df["Col A"].shift(-1) < df["Col A"]) &
            (df["Col A"].shift( 1) < df["Col A"]) &
            (df["Col A"].shift( 2) < df["Col A"].shift( 1))).astype(int)
df["TP"]
#1    0
#2    0
#3    0
#4    0
#5    0
#6    0
#7    1
#8    0
#9    0
```